# Need Home component that re-renders every time i click in it from drawer [react native]

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I have drawer screen named Home and it renders material top-tab navigator and other stack screen defined inside it.Problem is that i want to re-render home screen when i click it from other defined screens .Please help,this is the most general feature required in apps but i am unable to do it.
| iOS or Android | both
| @react-navigation/native 5.0.7
| @react-navigation/drawer 5.1.0
| react-native-reanimated 1.7.0
| react-native-gesture-handler 1.6.0
| react-native-safe-area-context 0.7.3
| react-native-screens 2.8.0
| react-native 0.61.5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7xLe.png)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by re render but if you want to run a function everytime the screen is opened you can use usefocuseffect hook https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect

Comment: i mean to refresh home screen to its initial state..when pressing home button of drawer screen,you can look above image

Answer (score -1):

You should use navigation events to detect particular screen focus and blur.
focus - This event is emitted when the screen comes into focus
blur - This event is emitted when the screen goes out of focus

Usage

```
    function Profile({ navigation }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      //This event is emitted when the screen comes into focus
      // do something
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return <ProfileContent />;
}


    function Profile({ navigation }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
      //This event is emitted when the screen goes out of focus
      // do something
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return <ProfileContent />;
}
```

For more details, you can read docs [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/)